# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have created two components Contact.js and about.js and i wanted to scroll to that these positions . im using useRef() and context api  for my contact it worked but for my about js it doesnt ..

About.js

```
import React, { createContext, useRef } from "react";
import {useWindowScroll} from "react-use";
import second from "../images/second.jpg";

import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";
import instagram from "../images/New folder/png/Instagram.png"
import github from "../images/New folder/png/github.png"
import Linkedin from "../images/New folder/png/Linkedin.png"
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const AboutMeProvider = createContext();

export default function About(props) {

    const aboutMeRef = useRef()
    
    // props.refList.push(aboutMeRef)
    console.log(props.refList)
    
    
    


    return (
        <div ref={aboutMeRef}>

              
            <AboutMeProvider.Provider value={aboutMeRef}>
                <Navbar />
            </AboutMeProvider.Provider>

            <div  className="h1 text-center mt-4  text-name about-heading ">About Me</div>
            <hr className="hr hr-blurry" />


            {/* second layer  */}

            <div className="row about-main  mt-4">
                <div className="col aboutCol1 text-center ">
                    <div className="about-secondCard  px-4">
                        <img className="about-secondImg   " src={second} alt="...." />
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div className="col  wannaKnow-main w-75  px-4 ">

                    <div className="h1 text-left mt-4 col2-text row  ">Wanna Know Me ?
                    </div>
                    <hr className="hr hr-blurry" />


                    <div className=" rowe text-left mt-3  col2-sentence ">

                        My name is Manglesh Kumar Born  in Gorakhpur. I'm doing my  graduation  of B. Tech Computer Science and Engineering  from Kanpur.
                        I am a confident patient and a quick learner.

                    </div>



                    <a href="/" className=" row knowMore btn   btn-lg mt-4 active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Know More</a>






                </div>




            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export {AboutMeProvider};
```

Contact.js

```
import React, { createContext, useRef } from 'react'
import { useWindowScroll } from 'react-use';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
const ContactProvider = createContext();

export default function Contact() {

    const contactRef = useRef()
    

    return (
        <>
            

            <div ref={contactRef} className='container contact-parent w-50 ' >
            <ContactProvider.Provider value={contactRef}> 
                <Navbar />
            </ContactProvider.Provider>
                <div className="h1 text-left   p-2 col2-text row  ">Get in Touch
                </div>
                <hr className="hr hr-blurry" />

                <form >
                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" />

                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">E-mail</label>
                        <input type="email" className="form-control" />

                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Number</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" />

                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlTextarea1" className="form-label"> Write Your Message here </label>
                        <textarea className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>


                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>


            </div>
        </>

    )
}

export {ContactProvider};
```

Navbar.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'

import { AboutMeProvider } from "../components/About";
import { ContactProvider } from './Contact';
export default function Navbar() {
  const aboutMeRef = useContext(AboutMeProvider)
  const contactRef = useContext(ContactProvider)

  const handleAboutBtn = () => {
    aboutMeRef.current.scrollIntoView()
  }

  const handleContactBtn = () => {

    contactRef.current.scrollIntoView()
    
  }

  return (

    <>
      <nav className="navbar-css-op navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light fixed-top">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <a className="navbar-brand text-dark" href="/">Manglesh</a>
          <button className="navbar-toggler bg-light" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link active text-dark" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <div onClick={handleAboutBtn} className="nav-link active text-dark"  >About</div>
              </li>


              <li className="nav-item">
                <div onClick={handleContactBtn} className="nav-link active text-dark" >Contacts</div>
              </li>
            </ul>


          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  )
}
```

i'm expecting to move to the respective component whenever i click on the NAvbar's links

Comment: You seem to have mixed refs and contexts.

Comment: `const aboutMeRef = useContext(AboutMeContext)` <- use `Context` instead of `Provider`

Comment: [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) could be what you're after here. Additionally, `ref.current` may be `null` or `undefined`, it may be worth having an `if` statement or conditional operator (`?`) before attempting to `scrollIntoView`